# How to enable the MySQL connection string "ENABLE_LOCAL_INFILE" when using Flyway in a gradle project?

Tags: java, mysql, gradle, flyway

There are several `.txt` files in my Java gradle project, which I use to populate a database using the MySQL statement `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` in `sql` scripts.

There is a MySQL server running on my PC, whose hostname is `127.0.0.1`, port is `3306` and DB name is `test`, so in the gradle project's `build.gradle` file I configure flyway in the following way:

```
flyway {
    url = 'jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test'
    user = 'root'
    password = '111111'
}
```

An example `.sql` file is

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data/categories.txt' INTO TABLE category
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

but when running migration using `gradle flywayMigrate -i`, I got the following error:
`Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides`

I think I have enabled it in the **server** side as shown below, which is a `MySQL Command Line Client` screenshot.
[image]
Hope I did it correctly.

After this step, the error still show up, so I think I also need to enable it in the **client** side, which is in the Java gradle project, is that correct?
Based on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data-local-security.html, I should set `ENABLE_LOCAL_INFILE = 1`.

But how to do that? In where should I add this `ENABLE_LOCAL_INFILE = 1` connection string?

Hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the JDBC connection string property `allowLoadLocalInfile=true`

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-connp-props-security.html#cj-conn-prop_allowLoadLocalInfile